# Ignore "The" when sorting sites alphabetically

Tags: feature-request, sorting, stackexchange.com, list

On the [Stack Exchange list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true), sites whose names start with "The" are sorted accordingly. It is [common practice to ignore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#The_and_other_common_words) "the" and other similar words when sorting alphabetically.

[image]

I suggest ignoring "the" when sorting the list.

Comment: I agree with you, but it is common practice to do it either way. My vote is to ignore The when sorting in this case.

Answer (score -3):

I disagree with everyone who had voted so far (26 upvotes to 0 down). I think "The" stands as part of the title in most cases here (not elsewhere/everywhere in life).

The "*the*" in your examples is used correctly so one can find them logically.
ie you wouldn't have "The Theoretical Computer Science", where as "The Great Outdoors" is logical.

I see your point and argument, but don't fully disagree.

The main key to success with any naming convention is very simply *consistency*.
If it's always the same then people become familiar with the structure. In fact, even if it's little weird and wacky and not particularly logical, as long as it's consistent throughout people can see the pattern used and work with it.

Also, you really have to consider that if your proposal is implemented it would actually counter your exact intentions, as people are very much accustomed to the way it is now, so the entire list being moved around would cause great issues with finding things.

Comment: The "consistency" you speak of would be to ignore "the" like *every other website* on the Internet. When I search for things, I never, ever go to T for titles that start with "the" - I wouldn't expect to find it there.

Comment: That's not consistency, that's a method. It might be "consistent with other websites" but Stack can't marry with all other websites. And are you really stating *all* websites do this? Besides, who cares what other websites do? Other websites allow forum like chat. So in your logic Stack should be consistent with those too? The only rules for consistency is that however you do something you do it the same throughout. Even if you had "The" at the start of everything. Here, "*the*" is used "consistently" within the search results.

Comment: As in, I have never encountered a site before that sorted including that article. The problem is that users across the web are used to that method, and would expect that same method be utilized wherever they look for something. Heck, even my phone ignores "the" in music titles. I'm not sure what you mean by search. Most search engines would completely drop "the" because it's never a useful search term, unless you're looking for information about the word itself.

Comment: iTunes ignores "A" and "The" at the beginning when sorting songs, artists, anything.

Comment: Search engines sort based back links (etc) not names. If iTunes negates "A" and "The" then that's stupid. What do I get if I search for the band "The The"? It'll be at "The" anyway due to the second "The". What about the song title "The Ocean Doesn't Want Me", I have to manually mentally drop the "The" even though it's the actual song title? That song title is still a sentence and so "The" can be defined still as a "definite article", however the song title is also a name where each word is specifically part of that name, and so "The" is not explicatively a "definite article".

Comment: Clearly more people think you're wrong.

Comment: @ColeJohnson "Clearly more people think you're wrong". Clearly. That must mean I'm wrong, and you 5 people are the majority vote representing the entire 2.5 million Stack OVerflow user base... This was more about personal opinion/preferences, and the people who have downvoted simply "don't like" it the way it is.